# Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value to data type int sql server

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, devextreme

I have a table. There is data in this table and there is a checkbox next to each data. Multiple selection is possible. After the user makes a selection, the id numbers of the selected columns are come in the array. I convert the array to string and send it to the stored procedure and I run the following stored procedure:

Example value for @ResultsIds: 65, 66, 67, 68, 125

```
@ResultsIds nvarchar(250)

UPDATE MyTable SET [IsVerified] = 1 WHERE Id IN (@ResultsIds)
```

And I got this error:

Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '65, 66, 67, 68, 125' to data type int. Because [Id] column is int data type.

I tried CAST and CONVERT functions of SQL but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server doesn't do that automatically. Assuming you're on a recent version, you can do this:

```sql
declare @ResultsIds nvarchar(250) = '65,66,67,68,125'

UPDATE MyTable
SET [IsVerified] = 1
WHERE Id IN (
   select [value] 
   from string_split(@ResultIDs, ',')
)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried split_string function but it requires 3 paramaters. I added third parameter as '' and tried again but now it gives "Invalid object name 'STRING_SPLIT" Error. I think it related to sql server compatibility level. I am working in corporate server and i can not change compatibility level. Is there another solution?

Comment: In re: three parameters, that is a failing of SSMS intellisense. It looks like MS is gearing up to add a third parameter to address a long-standing request to add an ordinal column to the result set that `string_split()` returns. But that isn't in any live version that I'm aware of. But if that function is not available to you, you'll have to revert to pre-SQL2016 methods (yes... it was introduced in a version that went live over five years ago).

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @ResultsIds nvarchar(250)='65,66,67,68,125'
UPDATE MyTable SET [IsVerified] = 1 WHERE cast(Id as varchar) IN (@ResultsIds)
```

Comment: Thank you, i tried this query. If there is only one value, it works, if there is more than one data, none of them are updated.

For example: 
ResultsIds = 65 (WORKING)
ResultsIds = 65, 66, 67 (IT DOES NOT GIVE AN ERROR BUT DOES NOT UPDATE)

Comment: Please remove white space like this and try again 

declare @ResultsIds nvarchar(250)='65, 66, 67, 68, 125'

set @ResultsIds=replace(@ResultsIds,' ','')

UPDATE MyTable SET [IsVerified] = 1 WHERE cast(Id as varchar) IN (@ResultsIds)

Answer (score 0):

I solved problem using foreach. I separated the numbers in the string from commas and transferred each number to the array. Then I updated the array one by one by running foreach loop.

```
public void Verify(DB db, string rows)
    {

        int[] nums = Array.ConvertAll(rows.Split(','), int.Parse);

        foreach (int value in nums)
        {
            DbCommand cmd = db.GetStoredProcCommand("VerifyProcess");
            db.AddInParameter(cmd, "@ResultId", DbType.Int32, value);
            db.ExecuteNonQuery(cmd);
        }

    }
```